# What's wrong with my Group By clause?

Tags: php, sql

Sorry for the stupid question, but I can't figure out why my data is displaying twice.

It's a very simple query. The DB table calendar_px currently has just three rows and four fields, including one for the date, another for the year and another (Brief) that includes some brief content.

So, if you visit the page MySite/Calendar/January_1, you should see all the years and briefs from the DB table that have a matching date (Date2) field (January_1). My practice table has three such rows:

```
1969 | So and so was born.
1969 | A volcano erupted.
1970 | They released a new song.
```

My code displays the information perfectly - except that it displays twice. I've grouped it by every field name, with and without the Cal2. extension, and nothing works. It looks like I must have made a really simple mistake, but I don't get it.

Here's my query...

```
    $stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT Cal2.N, Cal2.Date2, Cal2.Year, Cal2.Brief
        FROM calendar_px Cal2
        WHERE Cal2.Date2 = :MyURL
        GROUP BY Cal2.Brief");
    $stm->execute(array(
        'MyURL'=>$MyURL
    ));

    break;
}

while ($row = $stm->fetch())
{
    $Year = $row['Year'];
    $Brief[] = ''.$Year.' &#8211; '.$row['Brief'].'';
}
```

And this is what I have on the display page...

```
echo join( $Brief, '<br>' );
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: @Aidan - I don't want the sequence of three rows to display twice; I only want each row to display once. I thought the GROUP BY clause was the way to do that, though there may be other solutions I'm not aware of.

Comment: I don't think I understand. Can you append the current output to your question? If you just want each row to print once then you don't need a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: OK, here's my query without the GROUP BY clause...

     $stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT Cal2.N, Cal2.Date2, Cal2.Year, Cal2.Brief
      FROM calendar_px Cal2
      WHERE Cal2.Date2 = :MyURL");
    $stm->execute(array(
     'MyURL'=>$MyURL
    ));

But nothing changes; it still displays all three rows correctly, but then it displays all three rows a second time.

Comment: I think we need to see more of your PHP. I don't think your SQL is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$rows= $stm->fetchAll();
while ($rows as $row)
{
    $Year = $row['Year'];
    $Brief[] = ''.$Year.' &#8211; '.$row['Brief'].'';
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but I'm getting a syntax error on the second line - while ($rows as $row) I've been playing with it, but I haven't figured out what's causing the error yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yikes, I knew I did something stupid, and I finally figured it out. I somehow included the file with the query twice. I have to remember to use require_once rather than a simple require.